# How to save dynamic files from colab to Google Drive?

Tags: colab

I have processed some png images on Colab and saved them in the Colab Directory. Now I want to save these images from Colab to Google Drive. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just mount your drive into Colab and create the checkpoint in the mount point location. Let me try to explain this with an example:

1. Mount the drive as follows:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

This will mount your drive and your google drive files should be all under `/content/gdrive/My Drive/` location

2. Now use your location as you would use any other location in bash or create the check-point directory as follows:
   You can use the `!` to run bash commands in notebooks as follows:

```
!cp -r <PATH_TO_PNG_FOLDER> /content/gdrive/My Drive/
```